# Run @Before method once for all tests in @ParameterizedTest for Junit5

Tags: junit5

I have several @ParameterizedTest test method in my class.

I have static @BeforeAll method which runs before all @ParameterizedTest test methods once.

Now I need a mechanism to run a certain '@Before' method before each @ParameterizedTest test method (NOT before each scenario of @ParameterizedTest test but before test method annotated as @ParameterizedTest).

The issue is that @BeforeEach annotation will run your 'before' method before each scenario of @ParameterizedTest test but I need to run that once.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem, you can use `@Nested` for this

[Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60455744/3405109)

[Junit Docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-nested)