# Can we identify when a parameterised test finished all tests dynamically generated

Tags: java, junit5

Consider a scenario.
I'm performing API testing with validations on the payload fields of an object.

I prepare a prerequisite data in the database which is a valid `DataClass` Object for example.
Post which I provide that object to an `ArgumentsProvider` to generate field by field invalid values by tweaking one field of the provided valid object.

Normally, for other tests which are not `Parameterized`, I can tear down the data created for the test in `afterEachCallBack`, however, in case of using `ArgumentsProvider` I can't tear it down before all tests for that particular test function finish, otherwise after the first test, if I tear the data down (remove from DB) then it's not available for next test.

I have tried using `Function<DataClass, APIQuery> function` in some cases, but this leads me to create a valid data in DB for each iteration of test generated from `ArgumentsProvider`

Is it possible to identify, using `TestWatcher`, `TestExecutionListener` or `Extensions` or some other way, when the function which had dynamicallyGenerated functions has finished and moved to next function.
This way, I can tear down the data after all `Parameterized` tests have finished.

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to put the parameterized test method into ist own ˋ@Nestedˋ inner class and extend it with an extension that implements ˋAfterAllCallbackˋ.

Comment: I thought that, but the logic to remove and create data is being extended by default on all tests present using autodetect property (since it actually does make sense to extend for all)

I'll have to really pack it in a method and expose that to this AfterAllCallBack, but I'll also then have to someone see if I can deactivate the generic extension for these particular tests.

I have a lot of such tests to create a nested class and copy the logic for all of them which makes for a ton of boiler plate